# empty array values from unset()

Tags: php, arrays

I have this code:

```
for($count=0;$count<count($data['story_tags']);$count++){
    for($counter=0;$counter<count($data['story']['tags']);$counter++){
        if($data['story_tags'][$count]['tag_name'] == $data['story']['tags'][$counter]){    
            unset($data['story_tags'][$count]['tag_name']);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

What i'm doing there is unsetting similar array value(tag_name). I've googled how to delete array key/value and unset() was the most popular answer. Almost every post i went into answered that.

My problem now is that, there are empty/undefined array keys in my array now. since its an associative array.

This is what it looks like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [tag_name] => LitRPG ) [1] => Array ( [tag_name] => Virtual Reality ) [2] => Array ( [tag_name] => Cyberpunk ) [3] => Array ( [tag_name] => Reincarnation ) [4] => Array ( [tag_name] => Summoned Hero ) [5] => Array ( ) [6] => Array ( [tag_name] => Slice of Life ) [7] => Array ( ) [8] => Array ( [tag_name] => Non-Human ) [9] => Array ( [tag_name] => Anti-hero ) )
```

As you can see, it causes php notices popping up on my project for the undefined array values that was unset. I could simply just add an if(isset()) condition in my html but i would like to know if i am doing something wrong? and if not, how do i completely remove those empty arrays.

Or i could just remake the code and use an opposite logic `if(!matches){store into new array}`then again that would make my past array useless.

EDIT: just added `$data['story_tags'] = array_filter($data['story_tags']);` after the code.

Comment: You can easily use `isset()` on the key to make sure that array is set. If it's not, just skip it. As in `if(!isset($data['story_tags'][$count]['tag_name'])) continue;`

Comment: Yea, i wouldv done that but i found the array_filters first. 
I only do isset() if its within reason for example. a profile page. It has to have values but if no user is logged out and i try to enter the profile page.(i haven't done any user authentication as of yet since im focusing more on my other functions. my cookies keep expiring and i keep getting undefined variables).

Comment: This part of the function has no reason to be throwing empty variables though thats why i didnt want to use isset. 

Maybe im over thinking things. idk.

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice you already mentioned using `isset()` in your post, but that being said, `isset()` is always good to avoid undefined keys.

Comment: I'm relearning php/codeigniter since codeigniter was my framework from before i stopped. But im too hung up on the standard practices because i feel like i've wasted/lost 4 years of not coding.

Comment: @Rasclatt Just a quick question, idk how to google this.

if(!$value < 0){  }

would this work? I need to find out if a value is less than 0 or 0 and if not proceed. else.

Comment: You can use `empty()` there because the value `0` is considered empty and so is an empty value or `NULL`. So `if(!empty($value)){ // do stuff if not empty } else { // do stuff if empty }` also you can just use `if($value > 0)` without out the `!`.

Comment: I've been having troubles with this, last question.
$num = 1;
$prev = $num-=1;
$next = $num+=1;

if i echo both prev and next, prev will echo 0, next will stay 1.

but if i erase the '=' on prev. say $prev = $num-1;
the $next becomes 1. without changing anything on it.

even if i edit $next to $next = $num + 1;

It will stay as 1. but as soon as i remove '=' on $prev it adds up properly.